# ¿Como puedo saber cuanto tiempo tarda un método?

Tags: vb

Quiero saber cuanto tiempo tarda cada método al compilar mi programa.
ejemplo:

```
Sub Main()
--Aqui necesito que inicie el cronometro

    obtener_resultados()

--Aqui necesito que finalize el cronometro

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomas la hora actual al inicio, la vuelves a tomar al terminar y realizas el cálculo de la diferencia. En el ejemplo la diferencia está en segundos, aunque tienes más [opciones](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function).

```
Sub Main()
  Dim FechaI = Now
   obtener_resultados()
   Dim FechaF = Now
   Dim Diferencia As Integer = DateDiff("s", FechaI, FechaF)

End Sub
```